# CORS access-control-allow-origin

Tags: compiler-errors, cors, client, access-control, sanity

I am using Sanity studio to take care of my backend, and now that I have created my client.js and .env files to be able to access the data from sanity and implement it into my website, I am getting the CORS access-control-allow-origin error. I have the cors origin added in sanity, I have quadruple checked that my token and ID are correct, so I am not sure where this error is coming from. If anyone else has dealt with this or something similar please help me out, thanks!

I tried to make sure my Token and Id were correct. I downloaded a Cors origin changer. I have deleted and re added my cors origin on sanity a dozen times and still getting the same error over and over again.